# How to hide a whole a <div> if table <td> tag is is empty or null? (CSS Only)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide my div if all of my table tags are null or empty. If it is not empty then show the div that will show the table. I cant use jquery in this environment, so I am looking for a pure CSS solution. I believe the is a :empty tag that might work, but I don't know how to target the divs correctly.

```
  <div class="zpelement-wrapper field" id="elem_1562319120962" style="" gptype="html" eltype="related">
   <div class="singlebuild listArea">
    <div style="">
     <table style="width: 100%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" formcompid="3772761000000170459" layout="2">
      <tbody> 
       <tr> 
        <td class="labelcontent" style="width: 50%"> 
         <div style="">
          <label>Other Line Item</label> 
         </div> </td> 
        <td class="value" style="width: 50%"> 
         <div style="">
          <div class="listArea"> 
           <table width="100%" class="refValueTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" selectedfields="3772761000000170485,3772761000000170475,3772761000000170489" refformid="3772761000000170411" reffieldid="3772761000000170421"> 
            <tbody> 
             <tr>
              <th class="labelcontent" style="" formcompid="3772761000000170485"> <label>Product Category</label></th>
              <th class="labelcontent" style="" formcompid="3772761000000170475"> <label>Product</label></th>
              <th class="labelcontent" style="" formcompid="3772761000000170489"> <label>Cost</label></th> 
             </tr>  
            </tbody> 
           </table>
          </div>
         </div> </td> 
       </tr> 
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Can anyone help with any solutions?

Comment: we can use javascript?

Comment: No, it's unfortunately not available in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with css but you can rearrange your HTML in some ways and then use the pseudo selector :empty

```
div:empty {
   display: none;
}
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/

Answer (score 0):

**You can not do that with CSS only**, But you can hide empty cells in table using the following css:

```
table {
  empty-cells: hide;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however I am trying to remove the whole table, not just the empty cells. I am mainly interested in the table header not displaying. Is there a way to do that/?